# split strings inside a tsvector

Tags: postgresql, split, tsvector

I have a tsvector with values of strings(text) inside it.
I want to preform the split_part() function of postgres for each element inside the tsvector and to get a table with those values.
Is it possible?

Example:

tsvector: 'hello' 'world' 'thank you'

output after performing split_part(elementOfTsvector, 'o', 1) on each element:

**Table:**

'hell'

'w'

'thank y'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `unnest()` on tsvectors to get lexemes.

```
select split_part(lexeme, 'o', 1) from unnest('hello world ''thank you'''::tsvector);
```